# ¿Cómo se pronuncia en español el término "non sequitur"?

Tags: pronunciación, latín

Soy un estadounidense que vive en Uruguay hace unos diez años. Quisiera saber cómo ustedes pronunciarían la frase "non sequitur".

¿El "qui", si la fueran a utilizar en una conversación, cómo se pronuncia: en español o en latín?

(Y de paso añado también a mi pregunta: ¿la palabra *término* está bien utilizada en el título?)

Comment: Aunque no encuentro una definición en el D.R.A.E de "término" que se adapte exactamente a la acepción que empleas, creo que su uso aquí es correcto. Quizás la más cercana sea "palabra || (unidad lingüistica)" ya que aunque "non sequitur" está constituido por dos elementos, juntos definen un único concepto.

Answer (score 7):

De acuerdo con los ejemplos proporcionados por [**forvo**](https://es.forvo.com/word/non_sequitur/), y la experiencia de mi entorno lo confirma, parece que la pronunciación **habitual** (si no la correcta), es non se**cui**tur en vez de lo esperable, non se**ki**tur.

Parece que se pronuncia como en el idioma original, tal como es el caso de tantas otras palabras o locuciones:

- quid divinis [**cuid** divinis]
- quid pro quo [**cuid** pro **cuo**]
- quadrivium [**cua**drivium]
- nolle prosequit [**nole**-prose**cuit**]
- quod erat demonstrandum [**cuod**-erat-demonstrandum]
- etc.

Answer (score 2):

En el diccionario, las locuciones latinas están actualmente recogidas en cursiva: [*alma mater*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1x85zCG) (sin tilde), [*non plus ultra*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QbGMtW4), [*sine die*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xy5vzMe), [*urbi et orbi*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b8YCkJJ), [*quid pro quo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UpQTlt9)... Al menos, ese es el [criterio actual](http://www.rae.es/consultas/los-extranjerismos-y-latinismos-crudos-no-adaptados-deben-escribirse-en-cursiva), aun cuando hace años pudiese ser distinto (resalto en negrita el criterio actual y en cursiva el anterior):

> Según se establece en la nueva edición de la ortografía, **las locuciones latinas** [...] **deben recibir el mismo tratamiento ortográfico que las provenientes de cualquier otra lengua**. Por lo tanto, *aunque hasta ahora se recomendaba escribirlas en redonda y con las tildes resultantes de aplicarles las reglas de acentuación del español*, **deben escribirse**, de acuerdo con su carácter de expresiones foráneas, **en cursiva (o entre comillas) y sin acentos gráficos**, ya que estos no existen en la escritura latina.

En cualquier caso, esto quiere decir que se aceptan como **extranjerismos crudos**, y **su pronunciación ha de ser acorde a la del idioma original**:

> [**Tratamiento de los extranjerismos**](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/que-contiene/tratamiento-de-los-extranjerismos)
>
> **2. Extranjerismos necesarios o muy extendidos.** Son aquellos para los que no existen, o no es fácil encontrar, términos españoles equivalentes, o cuyo empleo está arraigado o muy extendido. Se aplican dos criterios, según los casos:
>
> **2.1. Mantenimiento de la grafía y pronunciación originarias.** Se trata de extranjerismos asentados en el uso internacional en su forma original, como *ballet*, *blues*, *jazz* o *software*. En este caso se advierte de su condición de extranjerismos crudos y de la obligación de escribirlos con resalte tipográfico (cursiva o comillas).

Lo mismo sucede con otros términos extranjeros como: [*copyright*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=An3ZN2Z), [*software*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YErlG2H), [*boutique*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=608tuXd), [*in crescendo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BEyRnAk)... que en español se pronuncian, aproximadamente: `/copiruáit/`, `/sófguer/`, `/butík/`, `/in creschéndo/` ([representación de sonidos según la RAE](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/representacion-de-sonidos)).
Y lo mismo pasa en inglés con palabras traídas del español que mantienen su pronunciación, como [*adios*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adios).

Yo aún diría más: aun siendo una locución muy conocida, lo cierto es que [***non sequitur* no está recogida en el diccionario**](http://dle.rae.es/?w=non%20sequitur), ni como locución ni como extranjerismo ni nada. Por tanto, técnicamente, estaríamos introduciendo en la conversación una expresión en otro idioma, y como tal debe pronunciarse en su idioma original: **`/non sekuitur/`**.

---

En cuanto al uso de "término" para referirse a una locución: habitualmente, "término" se usa significando una sola [palabra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZZ0hKcs#MWL7SfA), sin embargo gramaticalmente también es válido usarlo para referirse a un [segmento sintáctico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZZ0hKcs#SQO3wsj): un grupo de palabras que actúan como una sola.
En este caso, por tanto, creo que **es correcto decir "el término *non sequitur*"**, puesto que *non sequitur* funciona como una única palabra (de hecho no es posible dividirlo ni reordenarlo manteniendo el sentido de la oración en que se encuentre).

Answer (score 1):

Respecto a tu segunda pregunta, **la palabra "término" no es apropiada** para lo que tú refieres. "Non sequitur", "per se" o "ceteris paribus" (por nombrar algunos ejemplos) son locuciones latinas. **El término más apropiado, entonces, es locución.** De hecho, si buscas "alma mater" en el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas, encontrarás que éste lo clasifica como una locución latina (abreviado loc. lat.).

> alma máter. 1. **Loc. lat.** que significa literalmente ‘madre nutricia’.

**En cuanto a la pronunciación, lamento decirte que depende**. En ciertos contextos, es ampliamente aceptado que las locuciones latinas se castellanicen, es decir, su escritura y pronunciación se hace bajo las reglas del español. Por ejemplo, la RAE recomienda el uso de "Ibídem" en lugar de "Ibidem". Así, en tu caso, se pronunciaría "Non sekitur".

Sin embargo, en otros contextos (generalmente académicos), se considera apropiado respetar la pronunciación, escritura y morfología de las locuciones latinas. En estos casos, el uso de "Non sekuitur" sería aceptado.

Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Gran primera contribución. Sigue así, espero ver muchas más.